# A function's convergence speed to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f(x):(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ satisfying two properties

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x) = \infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)^nx = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

These two conditions give upper and lower bounds on how quickly $f$ tends to infinity as $x\rightarrow0$. I have the feeling that the upper bound implies that $f$ tends to infinity at most at logarithmic speed as $x\rightarrow0$, that is
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{\log(x)} \le M.
$$
Can someone reflect on the validity of this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{\log(x)} \le M$$
holds for any $M>0$ because $f(x)/\log(x)<0$  for $x\in (0,1)$.
If you mean that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{f(x)}{|\log(x)|} \le M$$
then the statement is not true because for $f(x)=1+\log^2(x)$:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x) = +\infty\, \quad
 \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)^nx = 0\;\; \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\quad
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{|\log(x)|}=+\infty.$$